# What's the most efficient way to generate a vector of values from -2 to 5 with a difference of 0.1 in R?

Tags: r

What's the most efficient way to generate  a vector of values from -2 to 5 with a difference of 0.1 in R?

Comment: Why not use `seq` i.e. `seq(-2, 5, by = 0.1)`

Comment: Can you say a little more about why you're interested in the most efficient method? Shortest/most elegant code? Or speed? (If the latter, is there reason to believe that this step is a computational bottleneck?)

Answer (score 2):

Use `seq` function,

```
seq(-2, 5, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`seq.int()` is known to be much faster than `seq()`.

```
seq.int(-2, 5, .1)
```

Alternatively, we could try a `while` loop,

```
(5 - -2)/.1 + 1  ## calculate number of steps
# [1] 71

i <- 1; r <- s <- -2  ## define starting values
while (i < 71L) {
  s <- s + .1
  r[i + 1] <- s
  i <- i + 1
}
print(r)
```

an even try integers.

```
ii <- 1L; ri <- si <- -20L  ## define starting values
while (ii < 71L) {
  si <- si + 1L
  ri[ii + 1L] <- si
  ii <- ii + 1L
}
print(ri*.1)
```

Looking at the benchmark (sequence from -2 to 1e5 used), the `while` loops are faster than `seq()` (ignoring the time to define the start values!!), but `seq.int()` is still faster.

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
       seq 8.857606 9.468344 11.579976 10.448676 12.225051  49.10238  1000   c
   seq.int 1.351898 1.495189  2.187937  1.720612  2.243119  25.16653  1000 a  
     While 3.777003 3.946604  4.797641  4.164015  4.365438 476.62461  1000  b 
 While.int 3.775510 3.930066  4.709157  4.155621  4.348228 410.80900  1000  b
```